# Include global .ocamlinit in local init

Tags: configuration, ocaml, toplevel

I'd like to include my global ~/.ocamlinit file when there is a project-local .ocamlinit as well, eg. in the local directory, since I do things like set my utop history file name in ~/.ocamlinit.

To that effect, I tried

```
#use (Filename.concat (Sys.getenv "HOME") ".ocamlinit");;
```

Of course that doesn't work, so I looked at [toplevel directives](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#sec298), but they all appear to take string arguments.  How best to do this?

I guess, more generally, the question is how pass non-constants to the top-level directives (not sure if the directives are preprocessed before any code is evaluated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the programmatical interface provided by the compiler-libs package. E.g.,

```
Topdirs.dir_use Format.err_formatter (Filename.concat (Sys.getenv "HOME") ".ocamlinit")
```

Should work without requiring any dependencies.